# implicit declaration of pivot root causing a compiler error

Tags: c, linux, containers, system-calls, mount

I have been getting these compiler errors when I am trying to create a self-made containers

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sys_pivot_root’; did you mean ‘SYS_pivot_root’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
TRY (sys_pivot_root(wd, "/dir/oldroot"));
```

And then I change sys_pivot_root into SYS_pivot_root then the following error message appears.

```
install_rootg.c:61:9: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
TRY (SYS_pivot_root(wd, "/dir/oldroot"));
```

and then I look into syscall.h to see if the function exists. I get the following line

```
asmlinkage long sys_pivot_root  (const char __user *    new_root, const char __user *   put_old)
```

why am I getting these compiler errors? I haven't been able to resolve this for like a week now.

I include the header files in this exact order.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
```

any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: According to a quick google search, the name of the function is `pivot_root`, and `SYS_pivot_root` is a defined constant to be passed as the first argument to `syscall`.

Comment: thansk for reply. The same issue arised with the pivot_root.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, so there isn't such function already defined as pivot_root.
you can just call syscall(SYS_pivot_root, ...
and pivot_root is called.
look at the man page for the usage.